# html anchor tag

Tags: html

I have the following div tag:

```
    <div id="headerimage"></div>
```

associated with this is the following css:

```
    #headerimage
    {
     width: 897px;
     height: 65px;
     background: url('../images/headerimg.jpg'); 
    }
```

I need the background image to be clickable to where when the user clicks it, it goes to url.

I did the following and it works but not sure if there is a more elegant way (Note how I have it within an anchor tag:

```
     <a href="http://www.myurl.com">
      <div id="headerimage"></div>
     </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nate,

You could just turn your anchor tag into a block element: http://jsfiddle.net/Vdfz8/

Hope that helps, and maybe even simplifies things for ya.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Might you know if this will be supported with older browsers - like say IE 6?

Comment: To anser your question directly, yes it should. Empty tags can throw back validation errors in some cases though. The usual solution to that is to add a non-breaking-space: "&nbsp;"